# \DeclareNameAlias{default} only for @author

Tags: biblatex

In a text, I'd like to have all authors' name in scshape.
However, if I use `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{scdefault}`
I obtain in scshape not only the authors' name, but even
the editor's one (for ancient texts). Is there a way
to set "selectively" the field to gain my result? Thanx

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ campanella:2010,
  author         = "Campanella, Tommaso",
  title          = "La città del sole",
  editor     = "Savinio, Alberto",
  publisher      = "Adelphi",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2010"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{scdefault}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[33-39]{campanella:2010}

\fullcite[67-77]{campanella:2010}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want this for authors only or for labelnames? The difference being that if you have collection where the editor is the person in charge this editor would not be printed in small caps in the former case, but would be in scshape in the latter.

Comment: mmmm... in this case I think it would be better to have author for books and editor for collections both in scshape

Comment: I think `scauthorscite=true` might do half of what you want. I'm still looking for an elegant solution for the other half though.

Comment: scauthorscite=true` seems to work only for authors - and authors only - in @book but with `\cite`, but not for `\fullcite` for, in this case, auhors and authors are no more in fcshape

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elegant solution, but one that works ...

First, define a command that allows us to switch to small caps

```
\newcommand{\makescshape}{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textsc}%
}
```

and one to switch back

```
\newcommand{\makenatshape}{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{}%
}
```

Now, using the [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package (that is, we need `\usepackage{xpatch}`) we inject these commands into the macros dealing with names in the bibliography: once at the beginning to switch to small caps, and then at the end to switch back to normal.

```
\xpretobibmacro{author}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\makenatshape}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{editor+others}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{editor+others}{\makenatshape}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{translator+others}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{translator+others}{\makenatshape}{}{}
```

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ campanella:2010,
  author         = "Campanella, Tommaso",
  title          = "La città del sole",
  editor     = "Savinio, Alberto",
  publisher      = "Adelphi",
  location       = "Milano",
  year           = "2010"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\makescshape}{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{\textsc}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{\textsc}%
}
\newcommand{\makenatshape}{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}{}%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}{}%
}

\xpretobibmacro{author}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{author}{\makenatshape}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{editor+others}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{editor+others}{\makenatshape}{}{}

\xpretobibmacro{translator+others}{\makescshape}{}{}
\xapptobibmacro{translator+others}{\makenatshape}{}{}

\nocite{matuz:doody,doody}
\begin{document}
\cite[33-39]{campanella:2010}

\fullcite[67-77]{campanella:2010}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might conduct some research on whether the set of patched bibmacros above is truly minimal (and indeed sufficiently large for marginal - and often overlooked - cases). That will not happen today though.

Comment: It seems me to work, even it's a lot of code|If you are so kind to search for a more minimalist and elegant code, thax a lot! no haste from me! :)

Comment: The new version of author/mantainer of biblatex-philosophy solves the problem